# Writing matrix inside an equation

Tags: equations, amsmath, matrices

I wanna type this equation. Normal equation/matrix code not working.

[image: Matrix equation]

Comment: show the code you have that is not working, then someone could fix it.

Comment: You problably need to use `align*` from `amsmath` as `equation` does not support more than one line. And as David mentions, post your code, much easier for us to help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 3):

Using `align*` with `bmatrix` can do the job (code hidden till you make a try!!):

[image]